# Not sure which verb to use after "did"?

Tags: past-tense, do-support

> - Did Esther **handed** her bag to you before she left?
> - Did Esther **hand** her bag to you before she left?
> - Did Esther **hands** her bag to you before she left?

Which of the three is grammatical?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Are you studying English? Have you learned to _conjugate_ English verbs? Please tell us where you found these three sentences. If we know what you already know, we can provide a useful answer. Please read our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages, and also our [**Details, Please**](https://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post.